# C# facebook sdk : (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Apps in the GK only need to pass TOS check

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I'm attempting to publish a video on a page using c# sdk and a simple form. Here is the code:

```
var fbp = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result1 = fbp.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = appID,
                client_secret = secretKey,
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            });
            fbp.AccessToken = result1.access_token;

           dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
           parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
           { ContentType =  "multipart/form-data",
             FileName = filename
           }.SetValue(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(textBox1.Text));
```

in the url string 1101387076701538 is the app page ID. The result is 
"Apps in the GK only need to pass TOS check" and I can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: You need to get a page access token to make API calls on behalf of your page. `grant_type = "client_credentials"` only gets you an app access token, you can not use that to post to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed the code in :

```
            dynamic result1 = fbp.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = appID,
                client_secret = secretKey,
           //      page_id = "1101387076701538",
                redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
                grant_type = "page_credentials"
            });
```

now the error is "Unable to load URL : Domain of this url is not included in App domains"
But I have included it in app domains. Where I'm wrong ?